# Why I can not click on my function to show and hide?

Tags: javascript

Hey I am having difficulty rewriting a code, but it is not working when clicking to show. How can I fix this issue. The code works opens up 500 then is suppose to work by click. But it does not work. Here is the code:

```
var timer;
$(".c_left").animate({ marginRight: "30px"}, "slow");
$(".c_right").animate({ marginRight: "215px"}, "slow", function () {
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $(".c_left").animate({ marginRight: "-155px"}, "slow");
        $(".c_right").animate({ marginRight: "30px"}, "slow");
    }, 500);
}); 
$(".icon-menu-2").click(function show() {
    $(".c_left").show.animate({ width: 200, marginRight: 30, display: 'toggle'}, 'slow');
    $(".c_right").show.animate({ marginRight:215, display:'toggle'}, 'slow', function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        });
}, function hide() {
    $(".c_left").animate({ marginRight: -155, display: 'toggle'}, 'slow');
    $(".c_right").animate({ marginRight:30, display:'toggle'}, 'slow');
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jL5hU/

How can I fix my code?

Comment: Check your console, you have an error. show should be show()

Comment: @Sergio Because I didn't test it, I'm on a tablet right now.

Comment: @bfavaretto, you were right... more things were missing :)

Comment: @Ljldsakj Akjdlakjfd, I see you never accepted an answer to your questions. It's good practise to do that since you will reward the people who answer with points. Hope my answer help you.

Answer (score 1):

As *bfvareto* commented `.show()` is a function and you cannot call it with just `.show`

You had strange code here also: `.click(function show() {`. Not quite sure what you mean there, anyway try my code suggestion...

```
var timer; var open;
$(".c_left").animate({ marginRight: "30px"}, "slow");
$(".c_right").animate({ marginRight: "215px"}, "slow", function () {
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $(".c_left").animate({ marginRight: "-155px"}, "slow");
        $(".c_right").animate({ marginRight: "30px"}, "slow");
        open = false;
    }, 500);
}); 
$(".icon-menu-2").click(function() {
    if(open){
        $(".c_left").animate({ marginRight: "-155px"}, "slow");
        $(".c_right").animate({ marginRight: "30px"}, "slow");
    } else {
        $(".c_left").animate({ marginRight: "30px"}, "slow");
        $(".c_right").animate({ marginRight: "215px"}, "slow");            
    }
    open = !open;
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZnFLf/)